# ¿Cómo consigo la ruta de un archivo que está dentro de mi exe?

Tags: c#

Estoy creando un launcher que hace instalar un modpack, solo que a mí sí me funciona bien, pero cuando lo comparto a un amigo le da error de que no se pudieron encontrar los archivos.

*Estos archivos los tengo dentro de mi proyecto en una carpeta*:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Así es como tengo las rutas*:

```
    private void btnInstalar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pathZip = "..\\..\\Resources\\.minecraft.zip";
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

        if (Directory.Exists(path + "\\.minecraft"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ya existe una carpeta .minecraft, debes eliminarla o cambiar el nombre para poder instalar el ModPack", "MAGIC ELITE LAUNCHER");

        }
        else
        {
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(pathZip, path);
            pxVerificado.Visible = true;
            btnPlay.Visible = true;
            MessageBox.Show("EL MODPACK HA SIDO INSTALADO CORRECTAMENTE!", "MAGIC ELITE LAUNCHER");
        }
        
    }
    private void bntPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pathLauncher = "..\\..\\Resources\\LauncherFenix.exe";

        Process.Start(pathLauncher);

        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: Lo estas mandando como recursos embebidos? o como archivos apartes?

Comment: como archivos aparte

Comment: Y los estas copiando en la carpeta de salida, y tambien mandando en tu instalador no? todo eso esta verficado?

Comment: si bro todo esta verificado

Comment: ¿si lo pongo como recurso incrustado como encuentro la ruta de este ?